# Node.js - Send non encrypted message before starting TLS

Tags: node.js, xml, ssl

everybody,
I have a project and want to create an XML interface for a security system.
The security systems are the host and I will develop the client in node.js in the first step and later for node-red.

Process description:
 - To establish a TLS connection the host receives an unencrypted STARTTLS command.

Procedure (Establishing the connection)

1. Start TCP connection
2. TCP connection established
3. Client to Host (STARTTLS)
4. Host is ready to receive the TLS client

When I start a TCP connection with "net" and try to forward the connection to "tls", the source port is changed and the host means that the tls part is a new client.
e.g.:

- connection "net" = source TCP port : 2483
- Connection "tls" = Source TCP Port : 2484

Many thanks in advance

```
var net = require('net');
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = 5555;
var host = '192.168.2.126';
var conn = net.createConnection(port ,host);


var options = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('client.pfx')
};


conn.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connected to server');
      conn.write('STARTTLS');

      connTLS()
     });


function connTLS (){
    conn = tls.connect(port, host, options, function() {
        // Check if the authorization worked
        if (conn.authorized) {
            console.log("Connection authorized by a Certificate Authority.");
        } else {
            console.log("Connection not authorized: " + conn.authorizationError)
        }

        // Send a friendly message
        conn.write('OK it works');

    });
}




conn.on('data' , function (data){
        var result = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        result+= (String.fromCharCode(data[i]));
        }
        console.log("Data received from the server: " , result);
        });
conn.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error in connection:', err);
      });
conn.on('close', function() {
       console.log('connection got closed, will try to reconnect');
         conn.end();
       });
conn.on('end' , function(){
      console.log('Requested an end to the TCP connection');
       });
```

Comment: Why do you want to create such a strange design in the first place? The usual way for a TLS upgrade (as can be found in SMTP, IMAP, POP, FTPS, ...) is not to create a new TCP connection with a different source port but to upgrade the current TCP connection to TLS by doing a TLS handshake inside the established TCP connection.

Comment: Many thanks for your help "Upgrade TCP to TLS" is that what I have searched but now I have a other Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your help "Upgrade TCP to TLS" is that what I have searched.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket

https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback >>> **socket**

```
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(startTLS,function (){
        console.log("request sent")
    })
```

```
var options = {
    socket: client,
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./Export/client.pfx'),
    secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method",
    rejectUnauthorized: false

}; 

var tlsSocket = new tls.connect(options)
```